# pre tags in tinymce adding br or p tags on ever line

Tags: php, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have been struggling to get the pre tags to work in tinymce.

For instance if I use the following code:

```
if($getcats_num > 0){

    $catlist .= '<select name="bcats" id="bcats" class="selectboxit">';
    $catlist .= '<option value="false">Select Blog Category</option>';
    while($fetchcats = $getcats->fetch()){
        $catlist .= '<option value="'.$fetchcats['id'].'"';
        if(isset($_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode'] == 'edit'){ if($fetchcats['id'] == $bcats){ $catlist .= ' selected'; } }
        $catlist .= '>'.$fetchcats['name'].'</option>';
    }
    $catlist .= '</select>';

} else {
    $catlist .= '<p>THERE IS NO CATEGORIES, BEFORE YOU CAN CONTINUE YOU MUST CREATE NEW BLOG CATEGORIES!</p>';
}
```

within the pre tags which are within the tinymce editor it then out puts it like this:

```
<pre>
<br>if($getcats_num > 0){
<p>$catlist .= '<select name="bcats" id="bcats" class="selectboxit">';
<br>$catlist .= '<option value="false">Select Blog Category</option>';
<br>while($fetchcats = $getcats->fetch()){
<br>$catlist .= '<option value="'.$fetchcats['id'].'"';
<br>if(isset($_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode'] == 'edit'){ if($fetchcats['id'] == $bcats){ $catlist .= ' selected'; } }
<br>$catlist .= '>'.$fetchcats['name'].'</option>';
<br>}
<br>$catlist .= '</select>';</p>
<p>} else {
<br>$catlist .= '<p>THERE IS NO CATEGORIES, BEFORE YOU CAN CONTINUE YOU MUST CREATE NEW BLOG CATEGORIES!</p>';
<br>}</p>
</pre>
```

I have tried everything to stop it adding br tags or p tags within the pre element.

I do not want to use php to simply wipe all p and br tags because then if it is used within the pre tags as a demo code then it will not show :(

Any ideas will be most grateful :)

Thanks

Comment: I amight be wrong but did you try `tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        force_br_newlines : false,
        force_p_newlines : false,`?

Comment: @stribizhev that would stop adding the p and br when not using the pre tags which is not how the editor is intended to work. To me this seams to be a bug with the coding of the pre tags, you do not get this with ckeditor or other editors like this

Comment: I see. Then, I guess, you will have to use a regex to remove `p` and `<br>` tags inside `<pre>`.

Comment: @stribizhev just tried it just to rule it out and the method you gave did nothing :(

Comment: @stribizhev then removing all p and br tags within the pre tags would mean I cant do what this is intended. This is so I can teach basic code on my blog page, but this would mean I can use the most used html elements if I can not use the p and br tags within the pre tags